# Calculating the average time between orders for each customer

Tags: sql, oracle

I've searched all over but cant seem to find how to calculate the average time between orders for each customer.  I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.  Ive tried using the lag() function with no joy.

Example data below shows a customer bought on 3 separate occasions.  The average time between all purchases is 7.5 days ((6+9)/2).

```
CustID   OrderDate 
-------  ---------
1000000  14-AUG-12
1000000  23-AUG-12
1000000  29-AUG-12
```

So how do I calculate that average for each customer?

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe look at this post : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307353/averaging-dates-in-oracle-sql][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307353/averaging-dates-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the key here is the [lag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) analytic function

```
select cust_id , avg(orderdate - lag_orderdate) as avg_time_between_orders
from (
    select cust_id , orderDate , lag(orderdate) over (partition by cust_id) as lag_orderdate
    from  orders )
```

Answer (score 7):

If only the mean average is needed then I think you can get away with a simple query without window functions by looking at the min and max dates and then diving by the number of gaps between orders:

```
SELECT CustID, (MAX(OrderDate) - MIN(OrderDate)) / (COUNT(*) - 1)
  FROM Orders
 GROUP BY CustID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Very logical solution, I ended up using cte as I wanted the average for all customers.

Answer (score 5):

The `LAG` analytic function is definitely the answer, but the query should go more like this:

```
SELECT CustID, AVG(OrderDate - PriorDate)
FROM (
  SELECT
    CustID,
    OrderDate,
    LAG(OrderDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY OrderDate) as PriorDate
  FROM Orders)
GROUP BY CustID
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Ed's answer as a starting point used CTE to get the average for all orders.

```
 WITH Sales_CTE (CustomerId, OrderDays, OrderCount)
    AS
    (
    SELECT CustomerId, (datediff(day,Min(OrderTime),Max(OrderTime))) / (COUNT(*) - 1) AS OrderDays, COUNT(*) AS OrderCount
      FROM tblStoreOrders  GROUP BY CustomerId HAVING COUNT(*) > 1  
    )
    SELECT Avg(OrderDays) FROM Sales_CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select customers.customerName, customers.CustomerNumber, T.date_diff as date_diff
 from customers 
join
(SELECT customerNumber, avg(datediff(shippedDate, orderDate))  as date_diff FROM classicmodels.orders group by customerNumber) AS T
on 
customers.customerNumber = T.customerNumber
order by date_diff
```