# Get average number of days

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on an SQL query that returns all customers who have placed at least 3 orders and also returns the average number of days between 1st and 3rd order.

I used this post as reference:

[Calculating the average time between orders for each customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300815/calculating-the-average-time-between-orders-for-each-customer)

and came up with below query:

```
select CUSTID , avg(OrderDate - lag_order)
from 
(select CUSTID , OrderDate , count(1) as total, LAG(OrderDate) over (partition by CUSTID ) as lag_order 
from ORDERS group by CUSTID having total >= 3)
group by CUSTID
```

But this is not the right syntax, here how to get the average number of days between 1st and 3rd order.

Also, I see that lag is a function in SQLServer, does this work for Oracle database also?

Comment: It looks to me that the question you linked is an exact duplicate, why doesn't the accepted answer work for you?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I want to get average number of days between 1st and 3rd order

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe you need to work with row number then since you want to look at specific orders and lag only handles previous

Comment: Why the average?. The time between order 1 and 3 for a customer is a single value. Could you post some data set example and the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

```
with orders as
(select 001 custid, date '2019-01-01' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 001 custid, date '2019-01-02' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 001 custid, date '2019-01-03' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 001 custid, date '2019-01-04' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 001 custid, date '2019-01-05' OrderDate from dual union all

 select 002 custid, date '2019-01-06' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 002 custid, date '2019-01-05' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 002 custid, date '2019-01-07' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 002 custid, date '2019-01-10' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 002 custid, date '2019-01-20' OrderDate from dual
)
select custid, avg(OrderDate - lg) average
from
   (select o.*, 
    count(*)            over (partition by custid) cnt,
    lag  (OrderDate, 2) over (partition by custid order by OrderDate) lg
    from orders o
   )
where cnt >= 3
group by custid;
```

Comment: Ahh, I never saw the offset parameter (2) in the lag function. But that is really nice. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I remember it comes from Oracle 8i.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like following using `ROW_NUMBER()` with self `JOIN` to find the first and third date for a customer.

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT custid, 
                orderdate, 
                Count(*) 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY custid) tot, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    partition BY custid 
                    ORDER BY orderdate)  rn 
         FROM   orders) 
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT t1.custid, 
               Datediff(day, t1.orderdate, t2.orderdate) Days, 
               t1.rn 
        FROM   cte t1 
               INNER JOIN cte t2 
                       ON t1.custid = t2.custid 
                          AND t1.rn = 1 
                          AND t2.rn = 3 
        WHERE  t1.tot >= 3) t 
WHERE  t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the average time for a customer between one orders and the order two orders back. Then a solution would be:
- First generate an ordered list per customer
- Then join each order with the one two steps back.

@akk0rd87: I borrowed your data.

```
with orders as
(select 001 custid, date '2019-01-01' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 001 custid, date '2019-01-02' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 001 custid, date '2019-01-03' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 001 custid, date '2019-01-04' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 001 custid, date '2019-01-05' OrderDate from dual union all

 select 002 custid, date '2019-01-06' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 002 custid, date '2019-01-05' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 002 custid, date '2019-01-07' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 002 custid, date '2019-01-10' OrderDate from dual union all
 select 002 custid, date '2019-01-20' OrderDate from dual
),
ordered_orders as (select custid, orderdate, row_number() over (partition by custid order by orderdate) onum 
   from orders o)
select co.custid, avg(trunc(co.orderdate) - trunc(oo.orderdate)) adays
from ordered_orders co, ordered_orders oo 
where oo.onum = co.onum - 2
and oo.custid = co.custid
group by co.custid;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use conditional aggregation.  One method is:

```
select custid,
       (max(case when seqnum = 3 then OrderDate end) - 
        max(case when seqnum = 1 then OrderDate end)
       ) / 2 as avg_1_3
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by custid order by orderdate)  as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by custid) cnt
      from orders o
     ) o
where cnt >= 3
group by custid;
```

A simpler way to express this is to use the `where` clause to filter down to the first three records:

```
select custid, (max(OrderDate) - min(OrderDate)) / 2 as avg_1_3
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by custid order by orderdate)  as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by custid) cnt
      from orders o
     ) o
where seqnum <= 3 and cnt >= 3
group by custid;
```