# Oracle 11G - NVL and AVG

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to embed an NVL expression within AVG. I am trying to subtract a start_date from the date_returned to determine length of a loan in months. If date_returned is null, I want to use today's date (sysdate). Here is a snippet from my statement:

```
avg(nvl(date_returned,sysdate)-start_date/30) "Loan Length in Months"
```

This is throwing the ORA-00932 error, inconsistent data type, expected NUMBER got DATE.

Any suggestions on how I can correct this statement?

Comment: I think you've omitted a set of parentheses — a start date divided by 30 makes no sense, but the difference in time (in days, presumably) divided by 30 does make sense.  Hence: `AVG((NVL(date_returned,sysdate)-start_date)/30)`.

Comment: I think you must convert your date in number and after you can apply an average function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307353/averaging-dates-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 0):

The error probably comes from the division:

```
SQL> select sysdate/30 from dual;
select sysdate/30 from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
```

Oracle allows to add/subtract from/to dates since it assumes the number means days:

```
SQL> select sysdate-1, sysdate+1 from dual;

SYSDATE-1 SYSDATE+1
--------- ---------
26-NOV-14 28-NOV-14
```

... but I couldn't figure out apossible meaning for multiplication/division.

As Jonathan points out, you probably forgot a parenthesis ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this,

```
avg(nvl(date_returned,sysdate)-start_date)/30 "Loan Length in Months"
```

Also your date_returned should be a date field, if its is NUMBER then you'd get ORA-00932 error, inconsistent data type, expected NUMBER got DATE