# Using decode with to_date

Tags: sql, powerschool

If anyone could help me with the following, I'd be grateful:
I'm trying to write a code (create an alert in PowerSchool) that will indicate if a student is younger or older than average for their current grade level. (For example, as student born before 6/30/2002 is older than average for 9th grade) I can't seem to make DECODE work in conjunction with >= TO_DATE. Here's my statement:

```
select lastfirst, decode  (dob >=  to_date ('2002-06-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'old') DOB
from students
where grade_level = 9
order by lastfirst
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably could get away with using a PowerSchool decode in your sql, but I find code easier to write when fewer languages/systems are included, so I would leave it out.  I would also let SQL do the average age calculation so you don't have to supply or calculate average dates yourself (see [Averaging dates in oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307353/averaging-dates-in-oracle-sql) for an explanation of the TO_DATE line).

```
SELECT
    LastFirst AS "Student Name"
    ,CASE WHEN dob >= (
        SELECT
            TO_DATE(ROUND(AVG(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(dob, 'J')))),'J')
        FROM Students
        WHERE Grade_Level = 9
        AND Enroll_Status = 0
    ) THEN 'Younger' ELSE 'Older' END AS "Older or Younger?"
FROM Students
WHERE Grade_Level = 9
ORDER BY LastFirst
```

The subquery calculates the average birthday, and the CASE statement compares each of your records against that, reporting if it's older or younger.

In the subquery that calculates the average, I've taken the liberty of assuming you only want to compare against currently enrolled students, since withdrawn students retain the same grade level.  You don't really want those students who left 10 years ago and are still listed as a 9th grader to mess with your average numbers.

Comment: That code works, but it seems to just split the class into two groups: younger and older. What I need is a code that lets us know if a student is "too young" or "too old" for each respective grade level. This is so if a student is struggling, we can tell at a glance if they should be retained in their current grade or are they too old?

Many thanks!

Comment: This was why I thought a decode function would work best... it would list all students, and just tag the very youngest and very oldest of each grade.

Comment: So you have a manually specified threshold of what is too old and what is young?  I think the CASE statement can be slightly modified to fit your needs, something like:

    CASE WHEN dob >= Date1 THEN 'Too young'
    WHEN dob <= Date2 THEN 'Too old' 
    ELSE NULL END